# Accessing Workflow Task ExtendedProperties by name

Tags: workflow, tasks

According to all of the articles I have read, including this one from Microsoft itself -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms520166(v=office.14).aspx, I should be able to access task form propeties using the `ExtendedProperties` property and the name of the field. For example, if my task has a field named `ActionComment`, I should be able to do something like

```
var comment = (reviewTaskAfterProperties.ExtendedProperties["ActionComment"] as string);
```

This, however, always returns `null`. Using the Visual Studio debugger, when I look at the ExtendedProperties property, every key is a `Guid`. What gives?

I know I can replace the above code with

```
var comment = (reviewTaskAfterProperties.ExtendedProperties[new Guid("5f4f18ad-7f5b-4d5d-879c-50b416acae3d")] as string);
```

but I would love to know if I am doing something wrong or not understanding the articles or something...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code I wrote in the past, I used the field GUID for the index when accessing ExtendedProperties, even for custom fields.

```
//For example:
var ActionCommentFieldGUID = workflowProperties.TaskList.Fields["ActionComment"].Id;

var comment = (reviewTaskAfterProperties.ExtendedProperties[ActionCommentFieldGUID].ToString());
```

Thanks for the question, btw.  I was updating my code and wanted to learn more about how the ExtendedProperties were populated.  Your link to the article on ExtendedProperties helped me.